# iPhone won't respect meta viewport larger than ~1000. Any value past 1000 is treated as ~1000! :(

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile-safari, viewport

The goal is to display a non-responsive website fully zoomed out on iPhones. In other words, the site should initially fit an iPhone screen without horizontal scrolling, then user can pinch to zoom in.

Normally, i don't need a viewport meta tag for that. When there's no viewport meta tag, the site will automatically be zoomed out to fit a mobile screen without horizontal scrolling.

But not when the site is wider than ~1000px! When it's wider, only the first ~1000px fit horizontally and horizontal scrolling appears.

Only iPhones have this behavior. On Android it's fine.

I tried to force a viewport with a corresponding meta tag and discovered that iPhone only respects the meta tag if its value is below ~1000.

E. g. if i set...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500;">
```

...the site is zoomed to 500px. If i set `width=900`, the site is zoomed to 900px.

But when i set it to...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1400;">
```

...then the site displays as if the width was 1000 or so.

Again, Android respects any width correctly.

The question is: how to i fit 1400px wide site into an iPhone screen, so that there's no horizontal scrolling when it loads initially, until user pinches in to zoom?

Here's a demo to fiddle with:  http://jsbin.com/luqari/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got this.

According to [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW26),

> The default value for minimum-scale is 0.25

Thus, a larger zoom level is enforced by default. So we have to loosen the minimum scale setting:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1400; minimum-scale=0;">
```